# mongodb version 2.4.9 what server should be connected

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch-river

I am trying to install mongoDB version 2.4.9 as this version is compatible with my Elastic search version 1.4.4. But I cannot find its server

It says

> W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 420BF4293BD7709A
>   W: GPG error: https://deb.nodesource.com trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1655A0AB68576280
>   W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/trusty/mongodb-org/2.4.9/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
>                                                                                  W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/trusty/mongodb-org/2.4/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
>                                                                              E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

When I do

```
 sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=2.4.9 mongodb-org-server=2.4.9 mongodb-org-shell=2.4.9 mongodb-org-mongos=2.4.9 mongodb-org-tools=2.4.9
```

It gives :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '2.4.9' for 'mongodb-org' was not found
E: Version '2.4.9' for 'mongodb-org-server' was not found
E: Version '2.4.9' for 'mongodb-org-shell' was not found
E: Version '2.4.9' for 'mongodb-org-mongos' was not found
E: Version '2.4.9' for 'mongodb-org-tools' was not found
```

What should I do to resolve it as I need compatible MongoDb and Elastic search version to install river plugin

Comment: 2.4.9 is very old and river plugins are deprecated in ElasticSearch 1.5 - are you really sure you wan't to base new work on this?

Comment: As per the requirement yes

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following commands in terminal

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 420BF4293BD7709A
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 1655A0AB68576280
```

And next:

```
sudo apt-get update
```